# Lost changes when changed the branch without commit

Tags: xcode, git

I am using this tool [Git GUI Tool](https://mac.github.com/). I have added few files as well as done changes in few files. Now by mistake I have changed the branch without commit. Now I can see the new files but with partial code not, lost some functions. Same with the modified files I lost almost all changes. So, any way to recover this changes.

It's XCode project.

I am badly stuck. Kindly point me in right direction.

Comment: if "changed the branch without commit" means what I think it does, just change back.

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't touch the untracked files when you switch branches. It also won't let you checkout if you didn't commit changes to the files you track. But this is git - who knows what this tool you are using does before checkout. It could have stashed your changes so check your stash if you haven't done this already.